# Tensorflow undefined reference to `tensorflow::TensorShapeBase<tensorflow::TensorShape>::TensorShapeBase(absl::Span<long const>)'

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow's C++ API to load and run a saved model. When I build my C++ code in GCC using the optimization flag `-O2` I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `tensorflow::TensorShapeBase<tensorflow::TensorShape>::TensorShapeBase(absl::Span<long const>)'
```

which I believe is due to the following tensor creation:

```
Tensor my_tensor(DT_DOUBLE, TensorShape({2, 4}));
```

However, if I build my C++ code without the compiler flag `-O2`, the code builds and executes perfectly. I am using Tensorflow 2.5 library that was built from source.

Any suggestions on how to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to a conflict between C++14 and C++17 when compiling Tensorflow with ABSL.
See this [link](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc/issues/266):

> Tensorflow_cc library uses own copy of Absl, and uses
> absl::string_view in function signatures. absl::string_view is mapped
> to std::string_view if C++17 is detected, and to own implementation if
> C++17 is not. That leads to linker errors like this when using Arch
> tensorflow_cc library from C++17 code:
> The workaround would be to comment out the lines: Using the library
> from C++17 after building libraries in C++11 mode (Arch)

One workaround is to comment out this line in tensorflow/include/absl/base/config.h:

```
#define ABSL_HAVE_STD_STRING_VIEW 1
```

This will make the library look for the custom absl::string_view implementation even if tensorflow is called from C++17.

Comment: In my case it was because I was linking against a different abseil version than was compiled with tensorflow. Updating my abseil to the same git commit that tensorflow used solved the issue.